# Repeated isearch when rebound to compound key

Tags: isearch

I don't isearch backwards frequently enough to justify giving it such a valuable keybinding, so I rebound `isearch-backward-regexp` to `C-c r` and I noticed that something strange started happening. Normally `isearch-backward-regexp` will use the previous search string and jump to the previous match if you hit `C-r` twice, but the search string in the minibuffer always cleared when you rebind `isearch-backward-regexp` to a compound keybinding.

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is because normally when you repeat an isearch command it executes the `isearch-repeat-forward` or `isearch-repeat-backward` command to save your search string (you can find this out by doing `C-h k` in the minibuffer). The following should fix this for your keybind:

`(define-key isearch-mode-map (kbd "C-c r") 'isearch-repeat-backward)`

Comment: Thanks! I didn't realize the `isearch-mode-map` was in effect